# Iframe not loading in webview android

Tags: javascript, android, iframe, android-webview

I have a webview. Everything is working fine but when I am opening a page which has iframe,  the iframe is not getting visible. Are there any specific settings required?

Comment: did you enable hardware acceleration ?

Comment: No.. Is it required?

Comment: Increased resources required to enable hardware acceleration, so try adding it to activity label or application label in manifest .

Comment: Why is iframe dependant on hardware accelaration

Answer (score 4):

First add [Hardware Acceleration](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html) and add the following lines to your webView

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

**EDIT 1**

It will be hard to identify the problem but try adding `WebChromeClient`, `WebViewClient` and also don't forget to enable javascript before loading `URL` like this

```
webView= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview); 
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); 
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); 
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

**EDIT 2**

If you really need to load content of iframe then Try using [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/download) to load html page but you have to find the iframe and fetch the content manually.

```
Document doc=...
Element iframe1 = doc.select("#iframe1").first();

if (iframe1!=null) {
   Document iframeContent = Jsoup.connect(iframe1.attr("src")).get();

  }
```

where `iframe1` is id of your `iframe`.

Comment: Why is hardware accelaration necessary?

Comment: @mohanmishra as I see many standard browsers and apps uses hardware-accelerated 2D graphics since long before. The main benefit is only extra boost in performance. It is recommended.

Comment: This is not working. Is there anything else that i can do??

Comment: @mohanmishra is that youtube iframe?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101058/discussion-between-mohan-mishra-and-shree-krishna).

Comment: @mohanmishra It's better using Jsoup. please try my second update.

Comment: This approach is not feasible. I have 3rd party pages opening. It will be virtually impossible to keep track of each n every iframe

Comment: It's ok, please kindly let me know if solved the issue in future, :) @mohanmishra

Answer (score 2):

This maybe a too late answer!
I hope it will help someone.

Just try to set up a desktop user agent to your webview

```
String DESKTOP_USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2049.0 Safari/537.36";
webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(DESKTOP_USER_AGENT);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you modify webview configurations and use loadData function to load iframe, some iframes will not work in webview. So for the solution I have implemented **AdvancedWebView** library.

https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView

Use loadHtml(URL) method with this webview and you can pass URL in parameter and you will be able to view iframe in webview.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if you have

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

in your AndroidManifest file, in the `<application>` tag of that activity.

Answer (score 0):

following hack worked for me for loading iframes in webview.Hope some one still might find it useful

```
 String webContent="your data to be loaded in webview";

if(webContent.contains("iframe")){
                Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("src=\"([^\"]+)\"").matcher(webContent);
                matcher.find();
                String src = matcher.group(1);
                webContent=src;

            try {
                URL myURL = new URL(src);
                webView.loadUrl(src);

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else {

            webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, "<style>img{display: inline;height: auto;max-width: 100%;}</style>" + webContent, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);}

    }
}
```

Also do not forget to add Internet permission in your manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Only thing that works for me, in Manifest:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

and in your Activity:

```
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```