# I have a problem with a PHP form on an iframe on my Android Webview

Tags: android, webview

I Have a php login form working perfectly on mobile browser but in my webview when the user press on the submit button the page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with "the page refresh" ? There is a blank page or nothing happens ?
You can intercept and proceed deep link ( e.g: a link in your webview ) like this :

```
  myWebView.setWebViewClient( new WebViewClient()
            {

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView inView, String inUrl)
                {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse( inUrl ) );
                inView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                return true;
                }

            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading( WebView inView, WebResourceRequest inRequest )
                {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, inRequest.getUrl());
                inView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                return true;
                }     
            } );
```

Comment: The page is loaded again with a blank form

Comment: shouldOverrideUrlLoading is not called in my case

Comment: FYI: The form is an iframe inside the html page loaded by the webview

Comment: Ok, could you try one of this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34871739/iframe-not-loading-in-webview-android ?

Comment: Final solution, I used Chrome Tabs. https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs